# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply') ionic-selectable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

**HTML**

```
<div class="grupoCampo" (click)="abrirBusquedaMaquina()">
        <label class="labelArriba">Maquina</label>
        <span class="maquina" contenteditable="false" [textContent]="maquinaSeleccionada" (input)="updateInput($event, 'maquinaSeleccionada')"></span>
        <div id="maquinaError">*</div>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
import { IonicSelectableComponent } from '@ionic-selectable/angular'; 

@ViewChild('busquedaMaquinas') busquedaMaquinas!: IonicSelectableComponent;

async abrirBusquedaMaquina(){
    console.log(this.busquedaMaquinas);
    this.busquedaMaquinas.open().then(async () => {
   }
}
```

Every time a try to open my ionic-selectable thow this error:

```
core.mjs:11483 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')
    at ionic-selectable-angular.js:28:71
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:412:30)
    at Zone.run (zone.js:166:47)
    at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (core.mjs:10917:28)
    at Prototype.<computed> [as open] (ionic-selectable-angular.js:28:27)
    at tarea.page.ts:5929:27
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:27:1
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1251:35)
    at zone.js:1158:21
    at zone.js:1174:37
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:6:1)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:27:1
    at ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:1340:25)
    at asyncToGenerator.js:19:1
    at TareaPage.abrirBusquedaMaquina (tarea.page.ts:5978:8)
    at TareaPage_ion_content_1_div_22_Template_div_click_1_listener (tarea.page.html:204:40)
```

this is the line width problems

```
const proxyMethods = (Cmp, methods) => {
    const Prototype = Cmp.prototype;
    methods.forEach(methodName => {
        Prototype[methodName] = function () {
            const args = arguments;
            return this.z.runOutsideAngular(() => this.el[methodName].apply(this.el, args));
        };
    });
};
```

and this is de object i got when i made the console.log(this.busquedaMaquinas);

**I'm using Ionic 7 but still using modules**

Comment: check if this.el has anything.

 if (this.el && typeof this.el[methodName] === 'function') {
        return this.z.runOutsideAngular(() => this.el[methodName].apply(this.el, args));
    }